# jQuery perform query against freshly parsed HTML

Tags: jquery

I have read the [jQuery documentation on context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context) and I think this should work:

```
var foo = $('<div class="bar"></div>');
foo instanceof jQuery;     //true
$('.bar', foo);            // returns []
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @j08691 get that div.bar of course. To get its contents for example.

Comment: don't you have it with `foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to search for element with class `bar` *inside* the `foo` element. However it is not inside - its the element itself.

This will work as you expect:

```
var foo = $('<div><div class="bar"></div></div>');
foo instanceof jQuery;     //true
$('.bar', foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bar', foo);
```

find all *descendants* that have a class of `bar`. Because your element has no descendants, this returns an empty jQuery object. Your code is equivalent to calling `foo.find('.bar')` (see [the documentation for `.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). What you could do is use the element's [*siblings*](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), like so:

```
foo.siblings('.bar');
```

This would work correctly, though it would not match descendants.